# SQL - Convert non-null adjacency list to path

Tags: sql, sql-server, path, filesystems, transitive-closure

I am working with some tables that represent a file system, and I need to select the full path of each folder as a flattened string.

The first table lists the details of each folder:

```
CREATE TABLE Folders(
    FolderID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(255) NOT NULL)
```

The second table lists transitive closures of folder relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE FolderClosures(
    FolderClosuresID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AncestorFolderID int NOT NULL, --Foreign key to Folders.FolderID
    DescendantFolderID int NOT NULL --Foreign key to Folders.FolderID
    IsDirect bit NOT NULL)
```

For sample data, let's assume the following folders exist:

```
Documents/
Documents/Finance/
Documents/HumanResources/
Documents/HumanResources/Training/
```

These would be persisted in those tables as follows:

```
| FolderID | Name           |
+----------+----------------+
|        1 | Documents      |
|        2 | Finance        |
|        3 | HumanResources |
|        4 | Training       |

| FolderClosureID | AncestorFolderID | DescendantFolderID | IsDirect |
+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+----------+
|               1 |                1 |                  1 |        0 |
|               2 |                2 |                  2 |        0 |
|               3 |                1 |                  2 |        1 |
|               4 |                3 |                  3 |        0 |
|               5 |                1 |                  3 |        1 |
|               6 |                4 |                  4 |        0 |
|               7 |                1 |                  4 |        0 |
|               8 |                3 |                  4 |        1 |
```

Some details to note:

1. Every folder has an "identity row" in `FolderClosures`, where `AncestorFolderID = DescendantFolderID AND IsDirect = 0`.
2. Every folder that is not a top-level folder has exactly one row in `FolderClosures` where `IsDirect = 1`
3. `FolderClosures` can contain many rows per folder, where `AncestorFolderID <> DescendantFolderID AND IsDirect = 0`. Each of these represents a "grandparent" or more distant relationship.
4. Since no columns are nullable, no rows explicitly state that a given folder is a top-level folder.  This can only be discerned by checking that there are no rows in `FolderClosures` where `IsDirect = 1 AND DescendantFolderID = SomeID` where `SomeID` is the ID of the folder in question.

I want to be able to run a query that returns this data:

```
| FolderID | Path                               |
+----------+------------------------------------+
|        1 | Documents/                         |
|        2 | Documents/Finance/                 |
|        3 | Documents/HumanResources/          |
|        4 | Documents/HumanResources/Training/ |
```

Folders may be nested at unlimited depth, but realistically probably only up to 10 levels.  Queries may require returning paths for a few thousand folders.

I've found a lot of advice on creating this type of query when data is persisted as an adjacency list, but I haven't been able to find an answer for a transitive closure setup like this.  The adjacency list solutions I've found rely on rows being persisted with nullable parent folder IDs, but that doesn't work here.

How can I get the desired output?

If it helps, I am using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get desired output is to do a recursive query. For this, I think the best is to only use the rows that have `IsDirect = 1` and use the anchor as all folders that don't have direct parent in `FolderClosures`, which should be all your root folders.

```
WITH FoldersCTE AS (
    SELECT  F.FolderID, CAST(F.Name as NVARCHAR(max)) Path
    FROM    Folders F
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM FolderClosures FC WHERE FC.IsDirect = 1 AND FC.DescendantFolderID = F.FolderID
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  F.FolderID, CONCAT(PF.Path, '\', F.Name)
    FROM    FoldersCTE PF
            INNER JOIN FolderClosures FC
                ON  FC.AncestorFolderID = PF.FolderId
                AND FC.IsDirect = 1
            INNER JOIN Folders F
                ON F.FolderID = FC.DescendantFolderID
)
SELECT * 
FROM    FoldersCTE  
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) --> how many nested levels you think you will have
```

This produces:

```
FolderID    Path
1           Documents
2           Documents\Finance
3           Documents\HumanResources
4           Documents\HumanResources\Training
```

Hope it helps.