# Query an adjacency list in SQL via a materialized path

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, adjacency-list, materialized-path-pattern

I have a large hierarchy (2,500+ records) stored in Microsoft SQL Server (2019) using an adjacency list model (e.g., `Id`, `ParentId`). I am looking for an efficient approach to look up a record based on a particular path in the hierarchy. In other words, given a path (e.g. `/Root/FolderA/SubfolderA`), I'd like to retrieve the `Id` associated with the final node (i.e., `SubfolderA` in this case).

> *Note*: Node names are not globally unique. I.e., we can't just look for `SubfolderA` and assume it maps to `/Root/FolderA/SubfolderA`. There may be multiple nodes named `SubfolderA` within the hierarchy.

## Setup

### Hierarchy

```
/Root
  /FolderA
    /SubfolderA
    /SubfolderB
  /FolderB
    /SubfolderA
    /SubfolderB
```

### Structure

```sql
CREATE 
TABLE   [dbo].[Tree] (
        [Id]            INT             NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        [ParentId]      INT             NULL, 
        [Name]          VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT      [FK_Hierarchy]  
        FOREIGN KEY     (ParentId) 
        REFERENCES      [Tree]([Id])
)
```

### Data

```sql
INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (1,    NULL, 'Root');
INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (2,    1,    'FolderA');
INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (3,    2,    'SubfolderA');
INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (4,    2,    'SubfolderB');
INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (5,    1,    'FolderB');
INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (6,    5,    'SubfolderA');
INSERT INTO Tree VALUES (7,    5,    'SubfolderB');
```

## Naïve Approach

There are quite a few threads on how to convert an adjacency list to materialized paths, including:

- [SQL - Convert non-null adjacency list to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717930/sql-convert-non-null-adjacency-list-to-path)
- [Build Enumeration Path from Adjacency List in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368657/build-enumeration-path-from-adjacency-list-in-sql)
- [Flatten Adjacency List Hierarchy To A List Of All Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764497/flatten-adjacency-list-hierarchy-to-a-list-of-all-paths/765077#765077)
- [Load hierarchical data from MSSQL with recursive common table expressions](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2019/03/31/load-hierarchical-data-from-mssql-with-recursive-common-table-expressions/)

### View

We can use one of these approaches to convert the *entire* adjacency list into materialized paths using an rCTE:

```sql
CREATE 
VIEW            [dbo].[MaterializedPaths]
WITH            SCHEMABINDING
AS 

WITH RCTE AS (

  SELECT        Id,
                ParentId,
                CAST('/' + Name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
  FROM          [dbo].[Tree] root
  WHERE         root.Id = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT        this.Id,
                this.ParentId,
                CAST(parent.Path + '/' + this.Name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
  FROM          [dbo].[Tree] AS this
  INNER JOIN    RCTE parent
    ON          this.ParentId = parent.Id
)
SELECT          Id,
                Path
FROM            RCTE as hierarchy
```

### Output

This produces the following output:

```
Id    Path
1     /Root
2     /Root/FolderA
3     /Root/FolderA/SubfolderA
4     /Root/FolderA/SubfolderB
5     /Root/FolderB
6     /Root/FolderB/SubfolderA
7     /Root/FolderB/SubfolderB
```

### Query

We can filter that output using a simple `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT          Id
FROM            MaterializedPaths
WHERE           Path = '/Root/FolderA/SubfolderA'
```

## Problem

The naïve approach works fine. The problem is that it's *incredibly* inefficient—and, thus, slow—for querying large hierarchies, as it needs to dynamically reconstruct the *entire* set of materialized paths each call. In my case, that takes 8-9 seconds. Obviously, I could just store this data in a table and regenerate it via a trigger at any time the data changes. But I'd *rather* find a more efficient query and avoid the additional complexity.

## Question

What is an efficient way of constructing this query? Or, at the risk of making this an XY problem, is there a way to limit the rCTE so that it only needs to evaluate the nodes in the hierarchy, instead of reconstructing the *entire* hierarchy each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to limit the rCTE so that it only needs to evaluate the nodes in the hierarchy, instead of reconstructing the *entire* hierarchy each time?

#### Limiting the rCTE

There are a handful of approaches to limiting the scope of each recursive query so that it's only evaluating the relevant nodes in the hierarchy. A fairly efficient approach is to simply restrict the rCTE to records which the source path (let's call that `@Path`) starts with:

```sql
INNER JOIN  RCTE recursive
  ON        this.ParentId = recursive.Id
  AND       @Path LIKE CAST(recursive.Path + '/' + this.Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'
```

This will limit the query to each record in your path:

```
Id    Path
1     /Root
2     /Root/FolderA
3     /Root/FolderA/SubfolderA
```

Which can then be easily filtered down to the final record based on a simple `WHERE` clause:

```sql
WHERE Path = @Path
```

#### Packaging it as a function

We can combine this with the original rCTE into a function. Putting it all together, it might look like:

```sql
CREATE
FUNCTION        [dbo].[GetIdFromPath]
(
    @Path       VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS         INT
AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE       @Id         INT = -1


  ;WITH RCTE AS (

    SELECT      Id,
                ParentId,
                CAST('/' + Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Path
    FROM        [dbo].[Tree] root
    WHERE       root.Id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      this.Id,
                this.ParentId,
                CAST(parent.Path + '/' + this.Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Path
    FROM        [dbo].[Tree] AS this
    INNER JOIN  RCTE parent
      ON        Tree.ParentId = parent.Id
      AND       @Path LIKE CAST(parent.Path + '/' + this.Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'
  )
  SELECT        @Id = Id
  FROM          RCTE as hierarchy
  WHERE         Path = @Path

  RETURN        @Id

END
```

#### Querying by path

Given the above function, you can now query the adjacency list by simply passing the full path to the `GetIdFromPath()` function:

```sql
SELECT          dbo.GetIdFromPath('/Root/FolderA/SubfolderA') AS Id
```

Which, given the sample data from the original post, will return `3`.

#### Performance

I've tested this approach against a table of comparable size, with 2,500 sample records, and it consistently executes well under a second, which is a dramatic improvement over the naïve approach. Obviously, you'll need to evaluate this against your own database and performance requirements to determine if its efficient *enough*.